# Reseting table and stopping table from replicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

Every time I exit the page and go back to it, another table is printed. Click on the 'click here' button and then click on the back button and then the 'click here' again to see the problem to see the problem. I want to prevent the code from printing a table every time I go back and forth from the two pages. Also I want to reset the table. If you click on a cell, it changes color and if you go back and forth from the page, the cell is still colored white.
I shortened the code down so it is easier to find the problem.

Code:

Js & jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page2').hide();

    $('#click').click(function() {
        $('.page1').hide();
        $('.page2').show();

        function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
            var grid = "<table>";
            for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
                grid += "<tr>"; 
                for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
                    grid += "<td></td>";
                }
                grid += "</tr>"; 
            }
            return grid;
        }

        $( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 10, 10) );

        $( "td" ).click(function() {
            var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
            var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
            $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'white' );
        });

        $('.back').click(function(){
            $('.page2').hide();
            $('.page1').show();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Tic-Tac-Toe Pro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page1">
            <p id="click">click here</p>
        </div>

        <div class="page2">
            <div class="back">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw96Z.png">
            </div>
            </br>
            <span></span>
            <div id="tableContainer"></div>
        </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .page1 {
            font-family:Calibri;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
    }

    div{
            display:inline-block;
    }

    #click{
            position:absolute;
            background-color:Yellow;
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 50;
    }

    .back{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left:10px;
            cursor: pointer;
    }

    img{
            width:20%;
    }

    .page2 {
            background-color: #B9D7D9;
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
    }

    td {
            border: 1px solid;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;

    }

    table {
           border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is this:

```
$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 10, 10) );
```

The append function is just going to add new content to the end of whatever is already in the tableContainer div.

Change it this:

```
$( "#tableContainer" ).html( generateGrid( 10, 10) );
```

And the content of that div will be replaced completely each time.